# SwiftUI - Randomly select two values from a database

Tags: swift, database, xcode, core-data, swiftui

In a database, I have an entity "Order" with two attributes ("name1", "name2"). I'd like to display in my view a value of "name1" and a value of "name2" at random but that the two displayed values match (with the same UUID).

So I used the code: "order.randomElement()!.name1" and "order.randomElement()!.name2" but the two values don't match. Do you have a solution?

My code :

```
struct ContentViewa: View {
        @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
        @FetchRequest(entity: Order.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "name1 != %@"))
        var order: FetchedResults<Order>

        var body: some View {

            VStack {
                VStack {
                    Section {
                        Text(order.randomElement()!.name1 )
                    }
                    Divider()
                    Section {
                        Text(order.randomElement()!.name2)
                    }
                }

                Button(action: {
                }){
                    Text("Next")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Same UUID means it has to be the same object so why not create a property that is initialised to `order.randomElement()` and get name1 and name2 from that property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is possible approach

```
struct ContentViewa: View {
        @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
        @FetchRequest(entity: Order.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "name1 != %@"))
        var orders: FetchedResults<Order>

        @State private var selectedOrder: Order? = nil
        var body: some View {

            VStack {
                VStack {
                    Section {
                        Text(selectedOrder?.name1 ?? "default")
                    }
                    Divider()
                    Section {
                        Text(selectedOrder?.name2 ?? "default")
                    }
                }

                Button(action: {
                }){
                    Text("Next")
                }
            }
            .onAppear { self.selectedOrder = self.orders.randomElement }
        }
    }
```